# Solving for a value inside of the sigma function, given a sum already.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions

I am looking to solve for the value of $p$, where $0 < p < 1$.

$$0.4 = \sum_{k=0}^{21} \binom{43 -k} k p^{(43-k)}(1-p)^k$$

I've looked through all my math textbooks, and cannot seem to figure out a solution. It would also be great if you can provide a solution using either R or Python as computing by hand can be very tedious!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A numerical method may be best here. Perhaps Newton's method?

Comment: http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/probability-distributions/binomial-distribution could be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

A question like this might be better for computer science stack exchange.   As for a program to solve it, because you'll be working with a degree 43 polynomial, you're gonna have to guess a lot of numbers.

I would gladly write a program and paste it here but unfortunately, just like my grades once were, I only know c, c++, and c#.  Instead, here's a pseudocode.

1) Create integer variables temp and previous.

2) $temp=-0.4+\sum_{k=0}^{21} \binom{43 -k }{ k } \left( \frac{p}{100}\right)^{(43-k)}\left(1-\frac{p}{100}\right)^{k}$.

3) Say you're guessing numbers between p=-3000 and 3000 (note that they're divided by 100).  Loop the above function 6001 times, increasing p by 1 each time.  After the first loop, set previous = temp.  After each loop thereafter, check if temp has the same sign as previous.  If they don't, this means that there's a root somewhere between.

4) After detecting a sign change between two numbers, you can print the average of the two numbers and continue incrementing p again, checking for other roots.  However, if you want extra precision, do the following.

5) If a sign change is detected between p=a and a+0.01, (for example, between 20 and 20.01) loop the following function 1001 times between, incrementing the value of n from 0 to 1000.

6) $temp=-0.4+\sum_{k=0}^{21} \binom{43 -k }{ k } \left( a+\frac{n}{100000}\right)^{(43-k)}\left(1-\left(a+\frac{n}{100000}\right)\right)^{k}$.

7) repeat step 4.  You now have an answer correct to 5 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the zero of function $$f(p) = \sum_{k=0}^{21} \binom{43 -k} k p^{(43-k)}(1-p)^k-\frac 25$$ in the range $0<p<1$.

As already said, only numerical methods will be able to do it and Newton method is probably the simplest.

The very first I should do is to expand the summation to get $$f(p)=p^{43}-14 p^{42}-14 p^{41}+1456 p^{40}-12649 p^{39}+53690 p^{38}-116116
   p^{37}+36608 p^{36}+519233 p^{35}-1560702 p^{34}+2135562 p^{33}-1045200
   p^{32}-1190007 p^{31}+2341598 p^{30}-1428952 p^{29}+5168 p^{28}+414086
   p^{27}-147136 p^{26}-19646 p^{25}+11704 p^{24}+1309 p^{23}+22 p^{22}-\frac{2}{5}$$

Then, marching by steps, I should try to bracket the solution. Here are some results 
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 p & f(p) \\
 1.0 & +0.600000 \\
 0.9 & +0.216484 \\
 0.8 & -0.209820 
 \end{array}
\right)$$
 So, using the iterative scheme $$p_{n+1}=p_n-\frac{f(p_n)}{f'(p_n)}$$ with, say, $p_0=0.85$ the successive iterates would be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & p_n \\
 0 & 0.85000000000000000000 \\
 1 & 0.85644248568377197111 \\
 2 & 0.85632152061985007588 \\
 3 & 0.85632148002864085143 \\
 4 & 0.85632148002863627602 
\end{array}
\right)$$ which is the solution for twenty significant figures.

Using any programming language, the procedure would be the same : first, bracket the solution marching by steps, then apply Newton method.

**Edit**

You could generate an easier starting point since you already start with very high powers of $p$ (namely $22$). So, as a first approximation, just solve$$22p^{22}=\frac 25\implies p=\frac{1}{\sqrt[22]{55}}\approx 0.833475$$

For a fast and efficient implementation, I would write a subroutine first which, for a given value of $p$ will return the value of the function and of its derivative with respect to $p$. This will look like

```
 SUBROUTINE FUNC(P,F,DF)
 F  = -0.4
 DF =  0.0
 DO K= 0 , 21
    A  = CHOOSE(43-K,K) * (P ** (43-K)) * ((1.-P) ** K) 
    DA = (1./ P - K /(1.-P)) * A
    F  = F + A
    DF = DF + DA
 ENDDO
 END
```

The main program will first try to bracket the solution and, when done, will start Newton procedure.